# Error Log When Calling a row of table

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, logging

Anyone knows Why this error?Occur when i select the row of a table,navigate to a view,then if i go back and select it again it just crash

```
-[CALayerArray name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a4f8a0
2011-08-24 01:01:10.983 Prototipo[8277:207] 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
     reason: '-[CALayerArray name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5a4f8a0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x010715a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x011c5313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x010730bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00fe2966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00fe2522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   Prototipo                           0x00003989 -[BaladaDetailsController setAllElements] + 129
    6   Prototipo                           0x00003cba -[BaladaDetailsController viewDidLoad] + 36
    7   UIKit                               0x00371089 -[UIViewController view] + 179
    8   UIKit                               0x0036f482 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 42
    9   UIKit                               0x0037ff25 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 48
    10  UIKit                               0x0037e555 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 43
    11  UIKit                               0x0037f7aa -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 326
    12  UIKit                               0x0037a32a -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 266
    13  UIKit                               0x00381562 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 932
    14  UIKit                               0x0037a1c4 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 62
    15  Prototipo                           0x00004bea -[TableViewBaladasController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 280
    16  UIKit                               0x00338b68 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1140
    17  UIKit                               0x0032eb05 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 219
    18  Foundation                          0x0004079e __NSFireDelayedPerform + 441
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x010528c3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 19
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x01053e74 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1220
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x00fb02c9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1817
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x00faf840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00faf761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x0192e1c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x0192e289 GSEventRun + 115
    26  UIKit                               0x002cfc93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    27  Prototipo                           0x0000261c main + 102
    28  Prototipo                           0x000025ad start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Answer (score 0):

You've probably have a memory management error and have over-released an object. Read the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html). If you show some of your code we can provide more help.